# "Мясо, жаренное по-французски" или "мясо жаренное по-французски"?

Tags: орфография, грамматика

Какой из этих вариантов является верным и почему? В интернете встречал оба написания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да хоть по-французски, хоть по-японски, наречия на "-ски" с "по-" пишутся через дефис.

Вот насчет одного или двух Н - это отдельная песня. 
Я, вопреки, возможно, мнению любителей догматизировать правила, думаю, что в данном случае "по-французски" относится больше к "мясу", чем к "жареному".

Поэтому предлагаю написание:
***Мясо жареное по-французски.***

А если кто настаивает на причастии, то и запятая нужна:
***Мясо, жаренное по-французски.***
Хотя и с запятой не исключаю, что можно трактовать как прилагательное, но это уже спор сугубо академический, настаивать не буду.

Comment: Насчет наречия, просто спутался.

Comment: И я настаивать не буду, но вполне допускаю и такой вариант: "Мясо жареное, по-французски". И пояснять по-моему, ничего не надо.

Comment: Да, по мне - так вполне возможно. Но при такой пунктуации  и сомнение в одном Н быть не может, "жареное" - очевидное прилагательное. А вот возможность использования "по-французски" в качестве определения, да еще однородного с "жареным" - это будут бой с тенью. ))).  Или Вы как-то по-другому будете запятую объяснять?!

Answer (score 2):

Ответ справочной службы Грамоты.ру
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]